# How to return null for certain values mysql

Tags: mysql

I am writing an outer join in sql to search a few tables and the code basically works except that I need it to return only the persons twitter link so if they have another social media listed or no social media at all it should return null but right now it returns all the social media links.  I tried using a where statement to see if smtype equaled twitter but that just returned the ones the had twitter and I need it to return all of them and just output null if it is something other than twitter. Plus it only needs to output each name once.

```
select fname, lname, rname, advisor_name, smaddr 
from PERSON 
join ADVISOR on PERSON.idnum = ADVISOR.student 
left join DIGITAL on ADVISOR.student = DIGITAL.idnum 
union 
select fname,lname, rname, advisor_name, smaddr 
from PERSON 
left join ADVISOR on PERSON.idnum = ADVISOR.student 
left join DIGITAL on ADVISOR.student = DIGITAL.idnum;
```

DIGITAL table where social media info is stored:

```
+-------+----------+------------------------------+
| idnum | smtype   | smaddr                       |
+-------+----------+------------------------------+
| 22222 | facebook | facebook.com/clemons.timothy |
| 40256 | facebook | facebook.com/south.william   |
| 68123 | facebook | facebook.com/smith.terry     |
| 22222 | twitter  | twitter.com/clemons.timothy  |
| 40256 | twitter  | twitter.com/south.william    |
| 68123 | twitter  | twitter.com/smith.terry      |
+-------+----------+------------------------------+
```

Current Output:

```
+----------+---------+-------------------------+---------------+----------------------------+
| fname    | lname   | rname                   | advisor_name  | smaddr                     |
+----------+---------+-------------------------+---------------+----------------------------+
| William  | South   | south.william@uky.edu   | Abby Tanner   | facebook.com/south.william |
| William  | South   | south.william@uky.edu   | Abby Tanner   | twitter.com/south.william  |
| Terry    | Smith   | smith.terry@uky.edu     | Nicole Taylor | facebook.com/smith.terry   |
| Terry    | Smith   | smith.terry@uky.edu     | Nicole Taylor | twitter.com/smith.terry    |
| Timothy  | Clemens | clemens.timothy@uky.edu | NULL          | NULL                       |
| Dan      | North   | north.dan@uky.edu       | NULL          | NULL                       |
| Courtney | Cox     | NULL                    | NULL          | NULL                       |
+----------+---------+-------------------------+---------------+----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the joining table requirement to its `ON` clause:

```
select fname, lname, rname, advisor_name, smaddr
from PERSON
join ADVISOR on PERSON.idnum = ADVISOR.student
left join DIGITAL on ADVISOR.student = DIGITAL.idnum and DIGITAL.smtype = 'twitter'
union
select fname,lname, rname, advisor_name, smaddr
from PERSON
left join ADVISOR on PERSON.idnum = ADVISOR.student
left join DIGITAL on ADVISOR.student = DIGITAL.idnum and DIGITAL.smtype = 'twitter'
;
```

Comment: Why does it not output the twitter link for Timothy Clemens even though they have a twitter.  It just outputs null but everything else it gets right.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select fname, lname, rname, advisor_name, 
    case 
        when smaddr not like 'twitter.com%' then NULL
        else smaddr
    end as smaddr
from PERSON 
join ADVISOR 
    on PERSON.idnum = ADVISOR.student 
left join DIGITAL 
    on ADVISOR.student = DIGITAL.idnum;
```

I didn't understand why do you use "union"?